# Visual Studio 2015 Property Formatting

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

When I enter automatic properties C# properties in Visual Studio 2015 it insists of formatting them like this:

```
public int Age {get;set;}
```

I don't want the space after the "e" and before the "{", I want it to look like this:

```
public int Age{get;set;}
```

I didn't have this issue in VS2013, and even though I've exported my settings from VS2013 and imported them into VS2015 it still insists on inserting that space!

No matter what formatting options I select I can't seem to get it to do what I want. Does anyone know what crazy option combination I need to select to get it to stop putting the space in?

Comment: **It makes code harder to read.** Don't do it. You should really write: `public int Age { get; set; }`. Notice that there are also space before and after `get;` and `set;`.

Comment: @Phil1970 - I disagree. When you see an expression such as `Print(1, 2, 3)` (for example) do you find it hard to read because there's no space after the 't' ?

Comment: Spaces are intended to separate statements. Thus one usually add more space between statements than between expressions.

Comment: If you work on some project with other developers, hopefully you all agree to use such convention. Because it's indeed uncommon and quite hard to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This automatic properties is part of the **Visual Studio Code Snippet**.

You should edit the default behavior for `prop`:
**File:** 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#\prop.snippet

And change:

```
<Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[public $type$ $property$ { get; set; }$end$]]>
```

To:

```
<Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[public $type$ $property${ get; set; }$end$]]>
```

Comment: @Phil1970 - Seriously Phil..!?!? Just because someone at Microsoft decides what they think is right it doesn't mean everyone else has to blindly follow (although that would appear to apply to you).

Comment: @Sean I doubt that the rule come from Microsoft...In any case, it is widely accepted that there should be space between statements.